# Retrieve list from object in Database

Tags: asp.net, list, object, get

I want to send a list of names contained in a Database using asp.net

These are my two objects:

```
public class Shop
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items{ get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to set a get controller in order to retrieve a list of items.
I did something like this:

```
 public IEnumerable<Item> Get(int id)
    {

        var items= new List<Item>();
        var shop= new Shop();

        using (var systemDB = new ShopsDB())
        {
                            it = systemDB.Shops.Where(s => s.ID == id).FirstOrDefault<Shop>();
                            items = it.Items;
        }   

            return items;

    }
```

This return `<ArrayOfItem i:nil="true"/>`.
I want to get the complete list of Items for one shop (e.g. shop with ID=1)

Comment: Instead of First Or Default use ToList();

Comment: because you are calling only 1 not the list, ToList(); will send you the complete list of the objects

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I need to return the list of items contained in the shop (e.g. with ID=1) not the list of shops ;)

Comment: is there any relation ship between the item and shop?

Comment: Yes, in the shop object is contained a list of Items. I need to retrieve it.

Comment: result = Items.AsQueryable()
                           .ToList()
                           .Select(c => new Item()
                            {
                                Id = c.Id,
                                Name = c.Name))

Comment: It doesn't work :( maybe there are problems using the foreign key... because in the database there is an additional field called Shop_Id and I can't set a query on it

Comment: Are these classes you provided ViewModels Or models that entity framework created in edmx file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved modifying the Item object:

```
public class Shop
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items{ get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ShopID { get; set; }
}
```

And set a query to select the ShopID

Answer (score 0):

This will return you the list

```
using (var systemDB = new ShopsDB())
    {
                        lab = systemDB.Shops.Where(s => s.ID == id).ToList();
                        items = lab.Items;
    }
```