# Put List<> into a SQL database table column

Tags: c#, database, join

I just had a similar problem here and I cannot figure out the solution (
[Retrieve list from object in Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34492175/retrieve-list-from-object-in-database) ).

I just want to know if it is possible to insert a list into a SQL database and how I get it back using a query.

Comment: Are you using an ORM? How do you want the list stored?

Comment: What you mean by *inserting a list in database*. Can you be little more specific.

Comment: I don't need the list in the database, I just need a relationship between two tables. And after using the primary key of the table to get a list of item from the other table that belong to the element of the first table :)

Comment: Use a Join SQL and use the ID to join the two tables.  See webpage : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213233(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

"SQL Database" is an SQL series database that has an EF driver? If so, then you could use code first to persist your list. ie: (this sample has many-to-many relation)

```
string defaultConString = @"server=.\SQLExpress;Database=CodeFirstDbSample;Trusted_Connection=yes;";

void Main()
{
    CreateSampleCodeFirstData();
    ListData();
}

private void CreateSampleCodeFirstData()
{
    var ctx = new MyContext(defaultConString);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    var c = new Customer { CustomerName="c" + i };
    ctx.Customers.Add( c );
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    var p = new Product { ProductName="p" + i };
    ctx.Products.Add( p );
  }

  ctx.SaveChanges();

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    var customer = ctx.Customers.Single (c => c.CustomerName == "c"+i);
    var products = ctx.Products.OrderBy (p => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(3);
    customer.Products = new List<Product>();
    customer.Products.AddRange( products );
  }

  ctx.SaveChanges();
}

private void ListData()
{
  var ctx = new MyContext(defaultConString);
  Console.WriteLine ("By Customer");
  Console.WriteLine ("".PadRight(50,'-'));
  foreach (Customer c in ctx.Customers.Include("Products"))
  {
    Console.WriteLine ("{0}: {1}", c.CustomerId, c.CustomerName);
    Console.WriteLine ("\t\t{0}", 
      string.Join(",", c.Products.Select (p => p.ProductName)));
  }
  Console.WriteLine ("".PadRight(50,'='));
  Console.WriteLine ();

  Console.WriteLine ("By Product");
  Console.WriteLine ("".PadRight(50,'-'));
  foreach (Product p in ctx.Products.Include("Customers"))
  {
    Console.WriteLine ("{0}: {1}", p.ProductId, p.ProductName);
    Console.WriteLine ("\t\t{0}", 
       string.Join(",", p.Customers.Select (c => c.CustomerName) ));
  }
  Console.WriteLine ("".PadRight(50,'='));
  Console.WriteLine ();
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
  public MyContext(string connectionString)
     : base(connectionString)  {}
  public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

}

public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId{ get; set; }
    public string CustomerName{ get; set; }
    public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: To increase performance, be sure to set these configuration:       `context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;`
`context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;`